# How to constrain a fieldset's width to a percentage of the screen

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I have a fieldset which I want to take 25% of the browser window.

```
html, body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

body:not(:-moz-handler-blocked) fieldset {
  display: table-cell;
}

fieldset {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset#rx {
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

While the fieldset is empty, it correctly occupies 25% of the window width.

As soon as some wide content is added, the fieldset expands to the size of its content, rather than staying at 25%.

How can I make the fieldset occupy 25% of the browser width, even when it has content?

---

Update: @rajuGT wrote a fiddle which illustrates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/of4dmkmk/2

Comment: Can you please include your markup, as well?

Comment: have you tried "resize: none;"

Comment: @SariRahal `resize` isn't widely supported

Comment: Hello, you try with all elements add percentage

Comment: I can't help but think you are misusuing `fieldset` here. I think we need to see the actual markup - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset

Comment: Add **your** HTML to the post please.

Comment: @TylerH the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/of4dmkmk/2 recreates the issue perfectly (for me, using FF).

Comment: @hungerstar - there are hundreds of lines of HTML, there's no point in posting *my* HTML, as the fiddle (above) demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry, as above.

Comment: Well at least a reduced case. The JS fiddle doesn't really clarify why you are using a fieldset here. It wouldn't normally be there **in isolation** as a wrapper for text.

Comment: @chrisdew you don't have to post all of it, just a snippet/section that is causing you issues. If that fiddle disappears nobody will know what the markup is that you're referencing in the future. Don't be lazy. Put it in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, fieldset has default min-width value (min-width: min-content;)

Edit: ehh that browser compatibility :(
Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/of4dmkmk/4/

Chrome and ff behaves differently.
Include min-width for chrome
wrap fieldset in a div for ff

Old answer.
for your #rx also use this:

```
fieldset#rx {
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  min-width: 25%; // I have added this
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: @chrisdew its working for the text content. and if I remove the css property mentioned by Remigijus, fieldset size is increasing. But I donno how its working. !

Comment: @rajuGT your fiddle shows a fieldset which occupies 40-50% of the window width.  I'm using FF.  Commenting out the `min-width: 25%;` makes no difference for me.

Comment: How about this http://jsfiddle.net/of4dmkmk/4/ . min-width was working for chrome, but not for firefox

Comment: Okay. But I didn't expect even that behavior from browser, after setting min-width property. makes no sense.

Comment: Many thanks, https://jsfiddle.net/of4dmkmk/4/ did the trick - min-width: inherit was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just place the fieldset inside a DIV, and then set the div's width to 25%, and set overflow to hidden?

Comment: I've already retreated back from that approach - the result was a fieldset whose right hand side, including the box, became hidden when the content was added.